# Cursor Pagination In Nodejs Messaging App

Tags: node.js, sockets, pagination, chat, message

I have searched for many forums before writing here. I have been facing problem in pagination in nodejs framework.

Offset or page based pagination won't work for me since it is a real time chat application.

I have tried implementing cursor for which I need a unique field. (Django gives the position of object from db as cursor in simple terms) We gotta do something same here.

There are 2 methods to resolve this:

1. To add another autoincrement value by chatId in document
   (feasible but I am looking to use _id)
2. to use _id
   But through _id, i am always getting an empty list.

Since mongodb gives objectId I want it somehow work with lt and gt and sort too

P.S. : Can't use updated_at or created_at, because we need to sort and updated_at gets changed everytime

I want to know the best practice to do this.